# How to check whether the postgres_fdw extension is installed in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I need to use postgres_fdw to link two database. According to [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html) guide, the first step is to install postgres_fdw extension.

How can I check this is already installed on the server or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I fond how to check it:

```
select * from pg_extension where extname='postgres_fdw';
```

[pg_extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/catalog-pg-extension.html) seems to have the list of installed extensions.